# How to make a solution target multiple .NET versions? (using NuGet and PCLs)

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a solution whose projects are targeted to the new .NET 4.6, but I would also would like to be able to compile a version compatible with .NET 4.5 without much hassle. The code is the same, no changes at all.

Is is possible to do it just selecting a Build Configuration for each Framework version?

I don't want to have a different csproj for each version. It would be a mess to keep them in sync.

REMARK: The project includes PCLs and NuGet packages.

Comment: Just having different configurations should be fine for the framework, not so much for NUGet. See [older thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000930/build-for-net-4-and-net-4-5-what-about-referenced-nuget-packages) for instance. I am still using a similar solution today but maybe something has changed in NUGet in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks, Stijn, but it seems to me that NuGet still doesn't have the ability to dynamically restore the references upon a change in the configuration :(

Comment: If you are building your nuget package using msbuild and a command line BAT file, just use the msbuild parameter to specify the .net framework version.

Comment: @Maarten I'm not building a NuGet package. I'm building the solution.